# I'm building a Shiny app in R and keep getting an error that says "Warning: Error in +: non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a Shiny app in R but every time I try to load it i get the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" - this error seems to be occurring in the renderPlot section in the server area.

I'm in the preliminary stages of building this and I'm not an expert in Shiny by any means. The app is supposed to load a chart based on the values from the projections that I'm scraping from FantasyPros. It was working when I was using regular data (as opposed to reactive data), but I can't seem to nail down the reactive part. Any help is appreciated!

```
if(interactive()){

        ## load required packages
        library(shiny)
        library(tidyverse)
        library(ggplot2)
        library(ggrepel)
        library(dplyr)
        library(agridat)
        library(rvest)
        library(tidyr)

        ## load latest projections from fantasypros
        scrape_projections <- function(position, week) {

            if (position == "qb") {
                naming <- c("", "PASS", "PASS", 'PASS', "PASS", "PASS", "RUSH", "RUSH", "RUSH", "", "")
            } else if (position == "rb") {
                naming <-  c("", "RUSH", "RUSH", "RUSH", "REC", "REC","REC", "", "")
            } else if (position == "wr") {

                naming <- c("", "REC", "REC","REC", "RUSH", "RUSH", "RUSH", "", "")
            } else {
                naming <- c("", "REC", "REC","REC", "", "")
            }

            # Be nice
            Sys.sleep(1)

            message(glue::glue("Scraping projected stats for {position} wk: {week}!"))

            url <- glue::glue("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/{position}.php?week=draft")

            url %>%
                read_html() %>% 
                html_table() %>% 
                .[[1]] %>% 
                filter(X1 != "") %>%
                set_names(nm = .[1,]) %>%
                .[2:length(.$Player),] %>% 
                set_names(., paste({naming}, names(.), sep = "_")) %>% 
                rename("Player" = "_Player", "FL" = "_FL", "FPTS" = "_FPTS") %>% 
                mutate(position = toupper({position}),
                       week = week) %>% 
                mutate(team = str_sub(Player, -3),
                       team = str_extract(team, "[[:upper:]]+"),
                       Player = str_remove(Player, team),
                       Player = str_trim(Player)) %>% 
                select(Player, team, position, week, everything()) %>%
                rename_all(tolower)
        }

        # define inputs
        position <- c("qb", "rb", "wr", "te")
        week <- "draft"

        # crossing for all combos of inputs
        crossing(position, week)

        # scrape the data
        projections <- crossing(position = position, week = week) %>% 
            pmap_dfr(scrape_projections) %>%
            mutate_at(vars(pass_yds, rush_yds, rec_yds), str_remove, ",") %>% 
            mutate_at(vars(pass_att:rec_tds), as.numeric) %>%
            mutate_at(vars(team:position), as.factor) %>% 
            select(-c("week")) %>% 
            as_tibble()

        ## set all NA values to 0
        projections[is.na(projections)] = 0

        ## set_vor function
        set_vor <- function(points_table, vor_baseline = NULL, vor_var = c("fpts", "floor", "ceiling")){
            if(is.null(vor_baseline))
                vor_baseline <- default_baseline

            vor_var <- match.arg(vor_var)

            vor_tbl <- select(points_table, "player", "position", vor_var) %>%
                rename(vor_var = !!vor_var) %>% group_by(position) %>%
                mutate(vor_rank = dense_rank(-vor_var), vor_base = vor_baseline[position]) %>%
                filter(vor_rank >= vor_base - 1 &  vor_rank <= vor_base + 1)  %>%
                summarise(vor_base = mean(vor_var)) %>%  ungroup() %>%
                select(position, vor_base) %>% inner_join(points_table, by = c("position")) %>%
                rename(vor_var = !!vor_var) %>%
                mutate(vor = vor_var - vor_base,
                       rank = dense_rank(-vor), !!vor_var := vor_var) %>%
                select(player, position, vor, rank) %>% rename_if(is.numeric, funs(paste(vor_var, ., sep = "_"))) %>%
                ungroup()

            return(vor_tbl)
        }


        ## 
        ## ui.R: defines a layout that will resize according to the size of the browser window; 
        ##       all the app code will be placed within the brackets of this

        ui <- fluidPage(
            titlePanel("2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator - created by Sam Hoppen"),
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    p("Select draft settings"),
                    selectInput(inputId = "league_size",
                                label = "1. Select league size",
                                choices = c("8", "10", "12", "14", "16"), selected = "12"),
                    selectInput(inputId = "draft_position",
                                label = "2. Select draft position",
                                choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"), selected = "1"),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "scoring",
                                 label = "3. Select scoring type",
                                 choices = c("Non PPR", "Half PPR", "Full PPR"), selected = "Half PPR"),
                    tags$p("Select starting lineup"),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_qbs",
                                label = "Number of starting QBs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "1",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_rbs",
                                label = "Number of starting RBs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "2",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_wrs",
                                label = "Number of starting WRs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "3",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_tes",
                                label = "Number of starting TEs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "1",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_flex",
                                label = "Number of starting flex spots",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "1",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_superflex",
                                label = "Number of starting superflex spots",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "0",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "bench_players",
                                 label = "Number of bench spots",
                                 choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),
                                 selected = "6",
                                 inline = TRUE),
    #                actionButton(inputId = "draft",
    #                             label = "Click to begin drafting!"),
                    selectInput("draft_pick_1",
                                "Round 1 Selection",
                                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_2",
                "Round 2 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_3",
                "Round 3 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_4",
                "Round 4 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_5",
                "Round 5 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_6",
                "Round 6 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_7",
                "Round 7 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_8",
                "Round 8 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_9",
                "Round 9 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_10",
                "Round 10 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_11",
                "Round 11 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_12",
                "Round 12 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_13",
                "Round 13 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_14",
                "Round 14 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_15",
                "Round 15 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player))
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    plotOutput("draftPlot")
                )
            )
        )

        ## server
        server <- function(input, output) {
            #            input$draft
            #            isolate(
            default_baseline <- reactive(
                c(QB = (input$league_size*(input$starting_qbs + input$starting_superflex)*1.25),
                  RB = ((input$league_size*(input$starting_rbs + input$starting_flex)*1.5) + (input$starting_superflex*input$league_size*0.5)),
                  WR = ((input$league_size*(input$starting_wrs + input$starting_flex)*1.5) + (input$starting_superflex*input$league_size*0.5)),
                  TE = ((input$league_size*(input$starting_tes +(input$starting_flex*0.5))) + (input$starting_superflex*input$league_size*0.25)),
                  DST = (input$league_size*0.5),
                  K = (input$league_size*0.25)))

                vor_table <- reactive(
                    set_vor(projections,
                                     vor_baseline = default_baseline(),
                                     vor_var = "fpts"))
            #            drafted_players <- projections %>% 
            #                filter(player = c(input$draft_pick_1,
            #                                  ))
            output$draftPlot <- renderPlot({
                ggplot() +
                    geom_smooth(data = vor_table(),
                                aes(x = as.numeric(fpts_rank), y = as.numeric(fpts_vor)),
                                color = "firebrick",
                                linetype = "dashed",
                                size = 1,
                                method = "loess",
                                formula = y ~ x,
                                se = FALSE) +
                    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 200),
                                    ylim = c(0, 150)) +
                    labs(x = "Player Draft Selection",
                         y = "Player Value Over Replacement",
    #                     caption = "Data from nflscrapR",
                         title = "2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator",
                         subtitle = "Created by @SamHoppen") +
                    theme_bw()
            })
        }
    }

    ## run app
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The error I'm getting after several errors related to packages not being loaded is `Error in crossing(position, week) : could not find function "crossing"`. And when I search for it in that long code block I see only a call to `crossing` but nothing being done with the results.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include loading the tidyr library!

Comment: OK, but the still doesn't explain what you are doing with that result.

Comment: You have no `numericInput` input boxes in your UI, yet you treat so many of them (`input$starting_qbs`) as numbers. `shiny` "knows" that these are strings. Humans read the strings and infer that the numbers should be quantitative, but `shiny` still thinks they are strings. Perhaps you should use `as.integer` or `as.numeric` on your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not testing the whole app, but you're assuming (incorrectly) that all of your inputs are numeric. Try the following:

```r
default_baseline <- reactive({
  req(input$starting_qbs, input$starting_superflex,
      input$starting_rbs, input$starting_flex, input$league_size,
      input$startting_wrs, input$starting_tes)
  l_sz <- as.numeric(input$league_size)
  st_flx <- as.numeric(input$starting_flex)
  st_sflx <- as.numeric(input$starting_superflex)
  st_qbs <- as.numeric(input$starting_qbs)
  st_rbs <- as.numeric(input$starting_rbs)
  st_wrs <- as.numeric(input$starting_wrs)
  st_tes <- as.numeric(input$starting_tes)
  c(QB = (l_sz * (st_qbs + st_sflx) * 1.25),
    RB = ((l_sz * (st_rbs + st_flx) * 1.5) + (st_sflx * l_sz * 0.5)),
    WR = ((l_sz * (st_wrs + st_flx) * 1.5) + (st_sflx * l_sz * 0.5)),
    TE = ((l_sz * (st_tes +(st_flx * 0.5))) + (st_sflx * l_sz * 0.25)),
    DST = (l_sz * 0.5),
    K = (l_sz * 0.25))
})
```

The first `req(...)` just makes sure that everything is non-`NULL` (which happens during app start-up) and something non-empty. The intermediate `as.numeric` are just to convert things; I don't take any effort to see if they convert correctly, though with radio buttons and selectors, it's likely to be fine.

One way you can verify this (and test any future errors) is to start your reactive block with `browser()` (for local testing only, does not work on a "proper" shiny server), such as

```r
default_baseline <- reactive({
  req(input$starting_qbs, input$starting_superflex,
      input$starting_rbs, input$starting_flex, input$league_size,
      input$startting_wrs, input$starting_tes)
  browser()
  l_sz <- as.numeric(input$league_size)
  # ...
})
```

When you get to that block, look at `input$league_size` and see what you have to deal with. From there, step through each line of your code to find where the error is being created. (When I say step through, perhaps run each line manually on the console instead of "stepping" through the code, that way if you type in an error, you stay within the debugging environment and can re-attempt code to insert into the real chunk. It's an imperfect process but helps you learn how to deal with these types of errors.

---

Why does this happen? If you look at various input types within shiny and read their help docs (e.g., `?selectInput`), you'll see something like the following:

```
selectInput               package:shiny                R Documentation

Create a select list input control

Description:

     Create a select list that can be used to choose a single or
     multiple items from a list of values.

...truncated...

Value:

     A select list control that can be added to a UI definition.

Server value:

     A vector of character strings, usually of length 1, with the value
     of the selected items. When 'multiple=TRUE' and nothing is
     selected, this value will be 'NULL'.
```

In that example, "Value" is what is returned within the UI element, so keeping that within `fluid_page` or similar is appropriate. However, when `input$someid` is accessed within the server environment, the "Server value" comes into play. In this case, a `selectInput`-created input will return a vector of character strings.

Your other input is:

```
radioButtons               package:shiny               R Documentation

Create radio buttons

Description:

     Create a set of radio buttons used to select an item from a list.

...truncated...

Value:

     A set of radio buttons that can be added to a UI definition.

Server value:

     A character string containing the value of the selected button.
```

(character string)

If you need a numeric vector, you can consider

```
numericInput               package:shiny               R Documentation

Create a numeric input control

Description:

     Create an input control for entry of numeric values

...truncated...

Value:

     A numeric input control that can be added to a UI definition.

Server value:

     A numeric vector of length 1.
```

but I don't think that's how you want to structure your user experience. In which case I suggest that you are "stuck" with having to convert everything from string to numbers manually.